# Make Jquery lavalamp the legend of a fieldset

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<fieldset>
            <legend>
                <ul class="lavaLampWithImage">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </legend>
        </fieldset>
```

I want to make the above fieldset have the JQuery lavalamp plugin AS the legend of the fieldset, so it looks like the fieldset lines go through the plugin image, like a real legend would be, then I'm eventually going to color the fieldset to match it.

```
$(function () { $(".lavaLampWithImage").lavaLamp({ fx: "backout", speed: 700 }) });
```

This is the code I use to create the lavalamp menu.

Here is how it comes out:

[image]

Is there anyway I can make it look right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting within a header tag and setting margins worked wonders :)

```
<h1 style="margin-top:-50px; margin-left:20px;">
            <ul class="lavaLampWithImage">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </h1>
```